# How to find the length of a string using ARM Assembly on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I am currently learning assembly using my RPI that has ARM architecture. I have created the code below. However, when I input a string ("hi" for example) a few things go wrong.
I do not receive the correct length. Example:   "Hi"  ->  length of 8 (obviously incorrect).
I will also segfault when the input is larger than 4 characters. Example:  "Hello" -> length of 8 and then segfaults.

I hope I am doing something obviously wrong! :) Thank you for your help in advance.

```
.data

/*Message1 */
.balign 4
message1: .asciz "Enter a string: "

/* Message 2 */
.balign 4
message2: .asciz "Your string has a length of %d\n"

/* Message 3 */
.balign 4
message3: .asciz "Your string is '%s'.\n"

/* format for scanf */
.balign 4
pattern: .asciz "%s"

/*Where we will store the length of the string */
.balign 4
strLen: .word 0

/*where scanf will store the string */
.balign 4
string: .asciz ""

/*Return value */
.balign 4
return: .word 0

/* Text Section */
.text

end:
        ldr lr, add_of_return /*load in the return address to lr */
        ldr lr, [lr] /* load the value at the address lr into lr */
        bx lr  /* branch exchange (basically end the program) */

add_of_return: .word return

calcStrLen:
        /*load in the first character to reg 2
          compare it to 0 and branch to label
          'done' if the two are the same */

        ldr r2, [r1]
        beq done

        /* increment the counter (r0) and the
           string pointer (r1) */
        add r0, r0, #1
        add r1, r1, #1

        /* store counter value into strLen */
           str r0, [r3]

        /* branch back to top of 'calcStrLen' */
           b calcStrLen

done:
        /* load the address of strLen to reg 1
           and then get the value at reg 1 and
           store it into reg 1 */
        ldr r1, add_of_strLen
        ldr r1, [r1]

        /* load in the address of message2 into
           reg 0 */
        ldr r0, add_of_message2

        /* print */
        bl printf

        /* branch to label 'end' */
        b end

.global main

main:
        /* load return address into reg 1
           and then get the value at the
           address and store it into reg 1 */
        ldr r1, add_of_return
        str lr, [r1]

        /* load address of message1 into reg 0
           and then print message1 */
        ldr r0, add_of_message1
        bl printf

        /* load in the necessary elements to
           scan in a string from the user */
        ldr r0, add_of_pattern
        ldr r1, add_of_string
        bl scanf

        /* prints the string given by the user */
        ldr r0, add_of_message3
        ldr r1, add_of_string
        bl printf

        /* load in the address of the user's string */
        ldr r1, add_of_string

        /*load in the address of strLen, then
          go to the address and store the value
          into r0 */
        ldr r0, add_of_strLen
        ldr r0, [r0]

        /* store strLen's address in reg 3 */
        ldr r3, add_of_strLen

        /* branch to label 'calcStrLen' */
        bl calcStrLen

/*Definitions of address values used */
add_of_message1: .word message1
add_of_message2: .word message2
add_of_message3: .word message3
add_of_pattern: .word pattern
add_of_string: .word string
add_of_strLen: .word strLen

/* external */
.global printf
.global scanf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string: .asciz ""
```

I'm pretty certain that just allocates enough memory for the string `""` (ie, one byte) and populates it, meaning you'll get the memory:

```
string: .byte 0
next:   ; whatever comes next
```

If you then go and store two or more bytes at that location (via `scanf()` for example), you're going to be in for a *world* of pain, as there'll be corruption of some description (at `next`).

*What* it corrupts depends on how your sections get laid out in memory.

Now, as to how to fix it, that depends on your assembler. Most will have a `.defs` type of pseudo-opcode for defining space of an arbitrary size, so you could do something like:

```
string: .defs 128
```

depending on what your assembler supports.

Comment: How could I allocate enough memory in my declaration of 'string' then?

Comment: I used '.lcomm string, 128'. This worked like a charm! thanks a ton!